# Regarding pointers and arrays and how they are assigned in memory in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

So I am trying to solve this question:

> Data is fed in the following input format. The first line contains two space-separated integers denoting the number of variable-length arrays, `n`, and  the number of queries, `q`. Each line  of the  subsequent lines contains a space-separated sequence in the format
>
> k A<sub>i</sub>[0] A<sub>i</sub>[1] … A<sub>i</sub>[k-1]
>
> where **k** is the length of the array, **A<sub>i</sub>**, and is followed by the **k** elements of **A<sub>i</sub>**. Each of the  subsequent lines contains two space-separated integers describing the respective values of array number (ranging from **0 to n-1**) and index in that particular array (ranging from **0 to k<sub>i</sub>**) for a query. i.e, Given the following input:

```
3 3
3 1 2 3
5 4 5 6 7 8
4 9 10 11 12 
0 1
1 3
2 0
```

> This output is expected

```
2
7
9
```

I am basically a beginner in C++. This is the code I have tried but I feel the address at which each subsequent array is stored is giving me some problems

```
int main(){
    int n, q;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);
    printf("n,q = %d, %d\n", n, q);
    int* row[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        int k;
        scanf("%d", &k);
        printf("k = %d\n", k);
        int col[k];
        row[i] = col;
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++){
            int elem;
            scanf("%d", &elem);
            printf("i,j,elem = %d, %d, %d\n", i, j, elem);
            col[j] = elem;
            cout << "address is " << &(col[j]) << "\n";
        }
    }
    for (int query = 1; query <= q; query++){
        int i, j;
        scanf("%d %d", &i, &j);
        int answer;
        answer = *(row[i] + j);
        printf("row[%d][%d] is %d\n", i, j, answer);
        cout << "address is " << &answer << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output produced:

```
n,q = 3, 3
k = 3
i,j,elem = 0, 0, 1
address is 0x7ffe236edb70
i,j,elem = 0, 1, 2
address is 0x7ffe236edb74
i,j,elem = 0, 2, 3
address is 0x7ffe236edb78
k = 5
i,j,elem = 1, 0, 4
address is 0x7ffe236edb60
i,j,elem = 1, 1, 5
address is 0x7ffe236edb64
i,j,elem = 1, 2, 6
address is 0x7ffe236edb68
i,j,elem = 1, 3, 7
address is 0x7ffe236edb6c
i,j,elem = 1, 4, 8
address is 0x7ffe236edb70
k = 4
i,j,elem = 2, 0, 9
address is 0x7ffe236edb60
i,j,elem = 2, 1, 10
address is 0x7ffe236edb64
i,j,elem = 2, 2, 11
address is 0x7ffe236edb68
i,j,elem = 2, 3, 12
address is 0x7ffe236edb6c
row[0][1] is 32766
address is 0x7ffe236edbcc
row[1][3] is 32766
address is 0x7ffe236edbcc
row[2][0] is 3
address is 0x7ffe236edbcc
```

Basically, I find that the array addresses are overlapping. Also, The answer computation by dereferencing is resulting in unexpected outputs. Any explanation to the mistakes made here would be appreciated.

Comment: `int k;.. int col[k];` is allowed in C not C++. `cout` is allowed in C++ not in C. I was going to suggest to change the tag to C but found `cout`... The only C++ thing used.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a major problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ...
    int col[k];
    row[i] = col;
    ...
}
```

The variable `col` has its scope only inside the loop. Once the loop iterates the variable cease to exist. Storing a pointer to it will lead to *undefined behavior* when you try to dereference the pointer.

The simple solution is probably to dynamically allocate memory for `col` using `malloc`.

---

Missed that the question was tagged C++, and confused because the source doesn't actually *use* any C++-specific code. This kind of makes it worse since [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not part of C++. Some compilers have it as an extension, but you should not use it when programming in C++.

Instead you should be using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and then you can easily solve your problem without your own dynamic allocation. Then you can make `row` a vector of vectors of `int` and `col` a vector of `int`, and then the assignment will work fine (if `row` have been set to the correct size of course).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to use C++ without getting too many memory management bugs is to use standard library types. Leave the bare metal stuff to the poor C guys who do not have that ;)

So instead of meddling with `new[]` and `delete[]`, use types like `std::vector<>` instead.

The "modern C++" version below uses iostream for no good reason. Old `stdio.h` is sometimes the preferred choice and so is sometimes `iostream`. And sometimes it is just a matter of style and taste.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

typedef struct Q
{
    int iArray;
    int iIndex;
} Q_t;

typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > Data_t;
typedef std::vector<Q_t> Query_t;

bool Load(Data_t& data, Query_t &queries, std::istream& is)
{
    size_t ndata = 0;
    size_t nqueries = 0;
    is >> ndata;
    is >> nqueries;
    data.resize(ndata);
    queries.resize(nqueries);

    for (size_t d = 0; d < ndata; d++)
    {
        size_t l = 0;
        is >> l;
        data[d].resize(l);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < l; i++)
        {
            is >> data[d][i];
        }
    }

    for (size_t q = 0; q < nqueries; q++)
    {
        is >> queries[q].iArray;
        is >> queries[q].iIndex;
    }
    return true;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::ifstream input("E:\\temp\\input.txt");
    Data_t data;
    Query_t queries;
    if (Load(data, queries, input))
    {
        for (auto &q : queries)
        {
            std::cout << data[q.iArray][q.iIndex] << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is, you have used *'col' array* which loses its scope after completion of for loop. The way you can **fix** this is by either using **dynamic memory allocation** or by **declaring it outside the for loop**

Hope the below code will help you get an idea :)

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int n, q;
    cin >> n;
    cin >> q;
    int* row[n];
    int* col;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        int k;
        cin >> k;
        col = new int[k];
        row[i] = col;
        for(int j=0; j<k; j++)
        {
            cin >> col[j];
        }
    }
    for(int query=0; query<q; query++)
    {
        int i,j;
        cin >> i;
        cin >> j;
        cout << row[i][j] << endl;
    }
delete[] col;
    return 0;
}
```